# Bumpers/contact sensors broken in Gazebo (Fuerte)?

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ANYONE have contact sensors working with Gazebo and Fuerte? If so, how did you get them working? I have sensors defined in the urdf of my model (and all the links have `<collision>` blocks), and the topics for the sensors are being advertised, but whenever I try to subscribe to the topics, I get a variation on this each clock cycle I'm subscribed to the topic:

```
Error [ContactSensor.cc:237] Contact Sensor[sensor_name] has no collision[link_name_geom]
```

At least part of the issue seems to have been fixed (Gazebo bitbucket issue 141), but I don't think the fix has made it to the released version yet. Also, issue 244 might still create problems, and a comment on issue 141 makes it sound like the bumper plugin might have problems as well. (Sorry about the lack of real links.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49202/bumpers/contact-sensors-broken-in-gazebo-(fuerte)?/) by [Elizabeth C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3009/elizabeth-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, is a problem with the gazebo on fuerte, read this [thread](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/13/contactsensor-in-gazebo-fuerte), but in this momment is better to wait for the update of the gazebo to the version 1.6.7... i'm having the same problem.. succes!

---

Originally posted by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) with karma: 172 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0